# How to access req.fields variables when using Express-Formidable

Tags: javascript, express, formidable

I am having a problem accessing variables which are being parsed inside of req.fields by Express-Formidable.
If I do a console.log() of req.fields I get the following:

```
{ 'registration[username]': '1', 
'registration[password]': '11' }
```

However, I cannot access the username or password field specifically. 
I have tried the following:

```
console.log(req.fields.registration.username)
console.log(req.fields.registration[username])
console.log(req.fields.registration['username'])
console.log(req.fields.username)
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys are awkward with the square brackets (`[` and `]`), but you can still access the values as they are just `String`'s at the end of the day.

You won't be able to use `req.fields.keyName` but you can use the square bracket notation i.e. `req.fields[keyName]`.

Two methods:

**Method A** - we use known key names

```
// We don't expect this to change
const usernameKey = 'registration[username]'

// Now let's extract the value
const usernameValue = req.fields[usernameKey]
```

**Method B** - Extract the keys and use them

```
const listOfKeys = Object.keys(req.fields)

listOfKeys.forEach(key => {
  console.log(req.fields[key])
})
```

Method B is a bit tougher to differentiate each value, but at least you'll be able to extract them.

Good luck!